# Issue with http://localhost:8983/solr in Sitecore configuration

Tags: sitecore-client, solr

I observed an interesting scenerio in my machine.
I have the following configuration:

```
<setting name="ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress" value="http://localhost:8983/solr" />
```

Now, If I go to Content Editor, I am getting the following error:

> **Value cannot be null. Parameter name: fieldNameTranslator**

But, if I go to Control Panel to build index, I could see all the indexes.

Now if I change the value from http://localhost:8983/solr to http://localhost:8983/solr/ ( just observe that I added "/" ) in the end, I am not getting any Content Editor errors, however, I could not see any indexes in control panel to rebuild index.

Anybody faced similar issue?

Comment: Do you see any issues in your logs on the SOLR site? Any Cores in your local folder that have the same name in core.properties folder? I created a blog for issues I ran into with SOLR recently. I saw the same error. https://sitecorerunner.com/2017/10/27/making-the-sitecore-switch-from-lucene-to-solr-with-custom-indexes/

Answer (score 5):

The issue got resolved. I found out that some cores are missing in Solr. Once I created them, it started working.
To add more details, In Sitecore logs I found that it is looking for the following cores :
social_messages_web
social_messages_master

I Manually added the cores to "solr-6.6.0-0\apache-solr\server\solr"
That resolved the issue.

Comment: Yep I have run into that issue too.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a little more detail about what the core was called (or example) and how you addressed it?

Comment: After your fix you use url without "/"?

Comment: Yes, after fixing the issue I an using url without "/"